# getURI() does not get the required url

Tags: java

I am running a struts application. I have a Save and Cancel link. When I press enter button, in my action class, the control does not go to Save link. So the getURI() function does not get any input, inturn throwing uncaught exception. How to get the control go the 'Save' link. Remember those are not buttons but link.

I dont have my piece of code right now. Will try posting later, but any quick help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post your fragment of code

Comment: public class lcprocessor extends tilesprocessor{ try{ logmanager.getTraceLogger().log((adapter.get adapter(request)).getuserinfo(), serverlogmanager.type_info_low,"lcprocessor:processroles- URI:" + request.getRequestURI()); } catch(Exception e) { sop("e:"+ e);}